# Basis of the n-th cyclotomic field over Q

Tags: cyclotomic-fields

How can one find a basis of the n-th cyclotomic field as a vector space over Q in a standard way ?

Thank you !

Comment: When proving it is a finite dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$ vector space, you have shown that $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n) \simeq \mathbb{Q}[x] / (\Phi_n) \simeq \{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} c_k \zeta_n^{\,k} , c_k \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ where $\Phi_n$ is the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_n$ (the cyclotomic polynomial)

Answer (score 1):

If $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]=r$, then $\{1,\alpha,\ldots,\alpha^{r-1}\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space.

Now recall that $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n):\mathbb{Q}]=\varphi(n)$.